# Unable to create database in sybase ASE 15.7

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

I'm trying to create db in sybase ase using command

```
create database au on default ="0.5g"
```

but it returns

Could not execute statement.
CREATE or ALTER DATABASE failed because the device 'default' has no
space available either for log or for data.
Sybase error code=1816
Severity Level=16, State=1, Transaction State=0
Line 1

create database au on default ="0.5g"

Size of my master db is 10 gb and it's all free

How to increase the size of the device 'default'?

Answer (score 3):

Run `sp_helpdevice` and check which devices are listed as 'default disk'. If your device is not listed as such, you can make it a default device by running `sp_diskdefault <devicename>, defaulton`.

BTW, it's generally not recommended to create additional databases on the master device, for reasons of recoverability in case of failures that will require rebuilding the server.